# AngularJS - Factory not working/activating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to work with AngularJS and a Web API written in VB.NET (Doing this for my internship).

I have my angularApp defined, same for my controller and factory.
I'm also working with the routing from Angular and this works perfectly.
The issue I'm dealing with is that my factory isn't activated or isn't working.

Please take a look at the code below:

My AngularApp.js

```
var angularApp = angular.module('AngularApp', ['ngRoute']);
    angularApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/ExpenseOverview', {
            controller: 'ExpenseController',
            templateUrl: 'Views/ExpenseOverview.aspx'
        })
        .when('/AddExpense',
         {
             controller: 'ExpenseController',
             templateUrl: 'Views/AddExpense.aspx'
         })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/ExpenseOverview' });
    }]);
```

My ExpenseController:

```
angular.module("AngularApp").controller("ExpenseController", ["$scope", "ExpenseFactory", function ($scope, ExpenseFactory) {
    //variabelen
    $scope.expenses = [];
    $scope.id = 0;
    $scope.date = "";
    $scope.type = "";
    $scope.title = "";
    $scope.project = "";
    $scope.status = "";
    $scope.img = "";

    var shown = false;
    var dataURL = "";

    ExpenseFactory.getList($scope);
}]);
```

So far my controller isn't doing much more other than retrieving a list of data from the database through the web API.

My ExpenseFactory.js

```
angular.module("AngularApp").factory("ExpenseFactory", ["$http", function ($http) {
    alert("test factory");
    var factory = {};

    //lijst van expenses ophalen
    factory.getList = function ($scope) {
        $http.post("/api/Expense/List")
            .success(function(data) {
                if (data === undefined || data == "") {
                    data = [];
                }

                $scope.expenses = data;
                $scope.id = $scope.expenses[$scope.expenses.length - 1].Id + 1;
            })
            .error(function() {
                alert("Er is een fout opgetreden");
            });
    };

    factory.saveList = function(expenseList) {
        $http.post("/api/Expense/SaveList", { 'expenses': expenseList })
            .success(function() {
                alert("Expenses have been saved succesfully!");
            })
            .error(function() {
                alert("Something went wrong while saving the expenses");
            });
    };
    return factory;  
}]);
```

As you can see, I have put an alert as the first line of code in the factory. This alert isn't even popping up, which means the factory isn't activating/working.

What is failing in this code?

**EDIT**
I updated my code to the current version with all the comments about things that might be interfering with the code. I can confirm that none of this was working, so the error is occuring somewhere else.

Another note: I'm working with Visual Studio 2012, if this might have something to do with it, please do elaborate how I can fix this shenannigans.

Comment: Is it because of " expenseFactory "  is it case sensitive. Not sure

Comment: You must use `angular.module('AngularApp')` in other files to reference th module

Comment: @mohamedrias why it is required, I think he has declared global variables..

Comment: Yup it's not required. But its a good practice to avoid polluting the global namespace. But the real error is in controller code. OP has a typo in referencing `expenseFactory`

Comment: It has been changed to angular.module("AngularApp"), as well as the expenseFactory being reverted back to ExpenseFactory. But still no difference when the code is being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @mohamedrias for helping me find to solution.
It was indeed because of the URL Path that was invalid.
Because of the view that couldn't be loaded, the factory was crashing alongside it.
I don't know how this happened, but it's fixed now!
All the code was correct, except for a reference to an invalid URL path for my views.

Thanks for all the help and comments, I'll keep everything in mind for the upcoming parts of my project.

StackOverflow is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You missed to return `$http` promise from factory methods

```
factory.getList = function ($scope) {
    return $http.post("/api/Expense/List")
        .success(function(data) {
            if (data === undefined || data == "") {
                data = [];
            }

            $scope.expenses = data;
            $scope.id = $scope.expenses[$scope.expenses.length - 1].Id + 1;
        })
        .error(function() {
            alert("Er is een fout opgetreden");
        });
};

factory.saveList = function(expenseList) {
    return $http.post("/api/Expense/SaveList", { 'expenses': expenseList })
        .success(function() {
            alert("Expenses have been saved succesfully!");
        })
        .error(function() {
            alert("Something went wrong while saving the expenses");
        });
};
```

Rather than passing whole scope, you should create one model object like `$scope.model = {}` and that will hold the all value of `ng-model` (scope variables) don't pass whole scope to factory, Pass only relevant data to service method.

Comment: The OP is asking, the first statement of `factory`  which is `alert("test factory")` It's more to do with controller code than with factory.

Comment: the return promise isn't helping at all since the first line of code in my factory isn't executing as well. I don't know what is happening when the factory is executed, but what I do know is that everything in my factory isn't being executed, apart from the "return" that I might have forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

As the app, controller and factory are in different files, it's better to avoid referencing the module using `angularApp`.

Instead use the following syntax:

```
angular.module('AngularApp').factory("ExpenseFactory", ["$http", function ($http) {
```

Here,

```
angular.module('AngularApp')
```

Means you're getting the module.

If you're going to use `var angularApp`, you're actually polluting the global namespace with your variable name.

Also if by chance in some other library code, someone reassigns it to something else then your entire application will break.

for example:

```
in another file, `angularApp = alert;`
```

And one more thing,

In your controller:

```
angularApp.controller("ExpenseController", ["$scope", "ExpenseFactory", function ($scope, expenseFactory) {
```

You have a typo in `expenseFactory` as it must be `ExpenseFactory`

```
angularApp.controller("ExpenseController", ["$scope", "ExpenseFactory", function ($scope, ExpenseFactory) {
```

Comment: still not working. The first line of code in the factory isn't even executing. I tried your code and replaced all the "angularApp" variables with the syntax you gave me. But it doesn't have any effect at all :/

Comment: Did you try my latest updated? You have a typo in your controller declaration part

Comment: the `ExpenseFactory` object we are using in function is not caseSensitive

Comment: Yes, I changed it and still no luck. It didn't do anything.

Comment: Could you please check your console and tell whether you see any error in browser console?

Comment: I booted up the project once more and the only error I'm getting was this
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - http://localhost:52661/Views/ExpenseOverview.aspx

Comment: It couldn't find the view you've mentioned in templateUrl. Make sure the URL path is correct